# Cant find object during Bind Operation in Controller

Tags: c#

Why cant i access an object when I am using db context. I have an issue I have a virtual object of notes inside my context but i cant access the bind object of a controller I should be able to find  MISObjectNotes but I cant

For Example

```
public class MISObject {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  [ForeignKey("MisNotes"), Column(Order = 1)]
  public int? NotesId { get; set; }
  public virtual MISObjectNotes Notes { get; set; }

}

public class MISObjectNotes {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

However When I try to do Bind it cant find the reference to MISOjbectNotes

```
public void SaveCase( [Bind("Id,Title,Summary") MISOjbectNotes --- here it cant find it]  { 
}
```

Even though in my context I have it as a DB Set in my context.

```
 public class MISDBContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> {
    public MISDBContext(DbContextOptions<MISDBContext> options)
        : base(options) {
        
 }
 public DbSet<MISObjectNotes> MISNotes { get; set; }
}
```

Any Ideas Why I cant access the object thru the Bind?

Comment: bind maps http request to c# object, not to a db entity

Comment: Hi @YegorAndrosov Yes I am using a Httpost on my Save for a ajax posted popup but cant i still decode it on the fly with the object?

Comment: @YegorAndrosov its fine sorted it below see answer

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the HTTPPost Decoration once I added it it was able to find the object.

```
[HttpPost]
public void SaveCase( [Bind("Id,Title,DateRias")] MISObjectNotes { 

}
```